# Phpmyadmin downloads file instead of opening dashboard (nginx) (linux)

Tags: php, mysql, linux, nginx, phpmyadmin

When I open localhost/phpmyadmin , it doesn't open the phpmyadmin agent but downloads a file containing php code

**my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

   server_name _;

   root /var/www/hewehi_nginx/html;
   index index.html;

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
}
```

Comment: You will need to configure Nginx to pass requests for php files to PHP. See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) or [search here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin%2bnginx?tab=Votes) for more examples.

Comment: I deleted nginx , php, phpmyadmin , mysql

downloaded xampp from scratch and same issue happens